# Unable to save extra field on extended Django-registration module

Tags: django, django-registration

I ve been following [Dmitry](http://dmitko.ru/django-registration-form-custom-field/) tutorial to extend django-registration plugins registration with an additional field. Users can be registered now but additional field is not saved. I keep getting the error.

> Django Version:1.4.2 
>   Exception Type: InternalError Exception Value:    current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block Exception
>   Location: /root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py
>   in execute_sql, line 910

Also looking at the postgresql logs, i see the following entry when i execute the register function.

> ```
> required" value="serkan" name="name" />', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E'') RETURNING "dirapp_userprofile"."id" 2013-03-03
> ```
>
> 12:28:45 EST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored
>   until end of transaction block 2013-03-03 12:28:45 EST STATEMENT: 
>   SHOW default_transaction_isolation 2013-03-03 12:29:59 EST ERROR: 
>   duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" 2013-03-03 12:29:59 EST STATEMENT: 
>   INSERT INTO "dirapp_userprofile" ("user_id", "name", "email", "phone",
>   "point", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "description") VALUES
>   (48, E'serkan', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E'')
>   RETURNING "dirapp_userprofile"."id" 2013-03-03 12:29:59 EST ERROR: 
>   current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block 2013-03-03 12:29:59 EST STATEMENT:  SHOW
>   default_transaction_isolation ransaction_isolation 2013-03-03 12:29:59
>   EST ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" ransaction_isolation 2013-03-03
>   12:29:59 EST ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" 2013-03-03 12:36:59 EST ERROR: 
>   duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" 2013-03-03 12:36:59 EST STATEMENT: 
>   INSERT INTO "dirapp_userprofile" ("user_id", "name", "email", "phone",
>   "point", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "description") VALUES
>   (49, E'serkan', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E'')
>   RETURNING "dirapp_userprofile"."id" 2013-03-03 12:36:59 EST ERROR: 
>   current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block 2013-03-03 12:36:59 EST STATEMENT:  SHOW
>   default_transaction_isolation 2013-03-03 13:02:10 EST ERROR: 
>   duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" 2013-03-03 13:02:10 EST STATEMENT: 
>   INSERT INTO "dirapp_userprofile" ("user_id", "name", "email", "phone",
>   "point", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "description") VALUES
>   (50, E'serkan', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E'')
>   RETURNING "dirapp_userprofile"."id" 2013-03-03 13:02:10 EST ERROR: 
>   current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block 2013-03-03 13:02:10 EST STATEMENT:  SHOW
>   default_transaction_isolation 2013-03-03 13:54:51 EST ERROR: 
>   duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "dirapp_userprofile_user_id_key" 2013-03-03 13:54:51 EST STATEMENT: 
>   INSERT INTO "dirapp_userprofile" ("user_id", "name", "email", "phone",
>   "point", "address", "city", "state", "zipcode", "description") VALUES
>   (51, E'serkan', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, E'')
>   RETURNING "dirapp_userprofile"."id" 2013-03-03 13:54:51 EST ERROR: 
>   current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block 2013-03-03 13:54:51 EST STATEMENT:  SHOW
>   default_transaction_isolation

Cant figure out what might be problem, hoping someone can spot me to right direction.

**models.py**

> class UserProfile(models.Model):
>
> ```
> user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
> name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
> email = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
> phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,null=True) 
> point = models.PointField(srid=settings.SRID, blank=True, null=True)
> address = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
> city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
> state = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
> zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True, null=True)
> description = models.TextField()
>
> def __unicode__(self):
>     return unicode(self.user)
> ```
>
> #Chcke whether the vendor box is checked    @property   def
>   is_vendor(self):      try:            self.vendor             return True         except
>   Vendor.DoesNotExist:          return False
>
> class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
>       class Meta:
>           model = UserProfile   exclude = ["user","point"]

**urls.py**

```
from djangoratings.views import AddRatingFromModel
from registration.views import register, activate
import dirapp.regbackend
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from dirapp.forms import UserRegistrationFormz
from registration.views import register
#import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls
import registration.backends.default.urls as regUrls


listing_list = {"queryset":Listing.objects.all()}


urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$',index,name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, { 'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class':UserRegistrationFormz}, name='registration_register'),  
    url(r'^accounts/', include(regUrls)), 
    url(r'^profile/$', user_profile, name='user-profile-view'),
```

**regbackend.py**

```
    from dirapp.forms import UserRegistrationFormz
    from dirapp.models import UserProfile
    from django import forms

    def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationFormz(request.POST)
        data = UserProfile(user=user)
        data.name = form.data['name']
        data.save()

    from registration.signals import user_registered
    user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from dirapp.models import UserProfile
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, RegistrationFormTermsOfService
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile
from forms import *
from django import forms

#class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
#    name = forms.CharField()

#    def save(self,user):
#        try:
#            data = user.get_profile()
#        except:
#            data = UserProfile(user=user)
#        data.name = self.cleaned["name"]
#        data.save()



attrs_dict = {'class':'required'}

class UserRegistrationFormz(RegistrationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict))
```

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'dirapp',
 'registration',
 'django_extensions',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'taggit',
 'djangoratings')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/posguide/../posguide/registration/views.py" in register
  187.             new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
File "/root/posguide/registration/backends/default/__init__.py" in register
  82.                                      request=request)
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/root/posguide/../posguide/dirapp/regbackend.py" in user_created
  9.     data.save()
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1593.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/root/env27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: InternalError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was trivial to solve. Slight modification to in query in regbackendpy got it working.

```
from dirapp.forms import UserRegistrationFormz
    from dirapp.models import UserProfile
    from django import forms

    def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationFormz(request.POST)
        **data = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user.id)**
        data.name = form.data['name']
        data.save()

    from registration.signals import user_registered
    user_registered.connect(user_created)
```